# DateTimePicker databindings

Tags: c#, data-binding, c#-2.0, datetimepicker

I'm trying to bind DateTimePicker control to a property of an object.

```
    DatePickerDataSale.DataBindings.Clear();
    DatePickerDataSale.DataBindings.Add("Text", document.Data, "DataSale");
```

Code for class document.Data looks like this:

```
private DateTime dataSale;
public DateTime DataSale
{
    get { return dataSale; }
    set { dataSale= value; }
}
```

Problem is that this databinding does not work. On

```
DatePickerDataSale.DataBindings.Add("Text", document.Data, "DataSale");
```

DataSale.get is called, but setter never executes. Where can be problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shouldn't you bind to **value** property?

```
DatePickerDataSale.DataBindings.Add("Value", document.Data, "DataSale");
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Stupid mistake caused by copying-pasting code from other controls